# how to load file.babylon ? it only shows loading scene

Tags: babylonjs

Hello i have problem with my project. i Try to load my babylon file but the file can't load. it only shows loading scene.
here is my code

```
var canvas, engine, scene, camera, score = 0;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    onload();
}, false);

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    if (engine) {
        engine.resize();
    }
},false);

var onload = function () {
    // Engine creation
    canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
    engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
    scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);

    initGame();
    initScene();

    engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
        scene.render();
    }); 

};

function initScene() {


    // Create the camera
    camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("camera", new BABYLON.Vector3(0,4,-10), scene);
    camera.setTarget(new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,10));
    camera.attachControl(canvas);

    // Create light
    var light = new BABYLON.PointLight("light", new BABYLON.Vector3(0,5,-5), scene);

    engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
    scene.render();
    });

}

function initGame() {
//BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("sphere", 10, 1, scene);
BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load("/assets/", "harimau.babylon", engine, function (newScene) { 
   // ...
});
}
```

this is my code and i dont know what to do with it to load my harimau.babylon file. thx

Answer (score 0):

Hello you may have to allow .Babylon MIME type on your server

Answer (score 0):

A solution that helped me is go to the Babylon.js main script file you are referencing and search for CrossOrigin and comment the two lines out. Then you will have to rename you SceneFileName.babylon to SceneFileName.js

Since your .babylon file is basically the a json object you can skip the register plugin process of the mimi type that babylon forces.

Cheers!